# ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms - Update 3 panels asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

Maybee I'm thinking of this the wrong way, I know the page renders and is sent to the client(webbrowser). But I really need to get to understand this.

**Question**
How do I update my three updatepanels asynchronously? To simulate this I have created a for loop which adds a second each time, after correct number is found and event is fired.
So what I want to do is to be able to see in the webbrowser, when these updates are done.
The time span would be like this:

**TIME**
0,0235(just a number toshow it really happens quick)
**What happens on the page?**
Almost instantly first label get's updated with number 7
**TIME**
0,0235 + one second = 1,0235 
**What happens on the page?**
Almost instantly second label get's updated with number 8
**TIME**
0,0235 + one second = 2,0235 
**What happens on the page?**
Almost instantly third label get's updated with number 9

I ahve visted pages that first show you some text and after a couple of seconds they show you a diagram, when that request has finished loading? So there must be a way rigth?

Heres my code, I'm not posting my CounterEventArgs class it works and doesn't affect the question.

Here's my index.aspx - codebehind
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private testClass _testet;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);  
}
void _testet_CounterFoundNumber(object sender, CounterEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.labelnumber)
    {
        case 1:
            Label1.Text = e.positionen.ToString();            
            break;
        case 2:
            Label2.Text = e.positionen.ToString();        
            break;
        case 3:
            Label3.Text = e.positionen.ToString();        
            break;
    } 
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testClass testet = new testClass();
    _testet = testet;
    _testet.CounterFoundNumber += new testClass.CounterEventArgsHandler(_testet_CounterFoundNumber);
    _testet.count();
}
}
```

And the Source

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Async="true"%>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>  
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel3" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
```

And lastly my testclass

```
public class testClass
{
public event CounterEventArgsHandler CounterFoundNumber; 
public delegate void CounterEventArgsHandler(object sender, CounterEventArgs e);
public int y = 1;

    protected virtual void OnCounterFoundNumber(CounterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CounterFoundNumber != null)
        CounterFoundNumber.BeginInvoke(this, e, new AsyncCallback(this.ResultFoundNumber), null);
    }

    public void count()
    {          
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i >= 7)
            {    
               OnCounterFoundNumber(new CounterEventArgs(i,y));
               y++;
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }              
        }
    }
    public void ResultFoundNumber(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        CounterFoundNumber.EndInvoke(ar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing in code behind try using Javascript [**setInterval method()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

In a JavaScript function **trigger some button click event** that does a partial postpack for you and update the panels.

If you want you can make the button as invisible by setting css property **disply:none**

Or please check implementing [**COMET in ASP.Net**](http://pokein.codeplex.com/) or ***WebSockets*** implementation if you use HTML 5.

Hope this would help you!

Comment: @Ravi: Thanks for your info. Is there any other source which explains very simply as w3schools does?

Comment: it may not be the simple one's, but accurate :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: @Ravi, Yes we do refer Mozilla. But sometime i give simple links which helps them to understand the basic use in one line :). Here i pointed that there is something in javascript.. they can refer more

Comment: hmm the seconds are only there to simulate different endingstimes of the asynv threads.  setInterval method() is not what I want.