# Getting the messages/notifications instantly without refreshing the page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a label which I show numbers in and numbers are the count of data from database. Whenever new data is saved in DB, the number in label should increase. It increases when i refresh the page, because I call the method on page_load in codebehind.

What in my mind is that:

- I should call the method periodically without refreshing the page.

For this purpose, I know that I should use AJAX, but I couldnt find appropriate usage for me.

Can you direct me to a solution?

This is the label on aspx page:

```
   <div id="panoramCouponBarLittleTalep">
      <asp:Label ID="LabelTalepSayisiSag" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="" runat="server" />
   </div>
```

This is the page_load :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {                  
                SonBesGunTalepSayisi();
            }               
        }            
    }
```

And the method I use:

```
 private void SonBesGunTalepSayisi()
    {
        RequestProvider rP = new RequestProvider();

        int talepSayisi = rP.LastFiveDaysRequestCount();

        if (talepSayisi > 0)
        {
            LabelTalepSayisiSag.Text = talepSayisi.ToString();

        }
        else
        {               
            LabelTalepSayisi.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms - Update 3 panels asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754553/asp-net-4-0-webforms-update-3-panels-asynchronously)

Comment: I use a ashx (ihttphandler) that would return the result to the label. Calling that handler at x seconds interval and setting innertext on the label .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method to be the server endpoint that your JavaScript AJAX will call, based upon a timer; like this:

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRequestCount()
{
    RequestProvider rP = new RequestProvider();

    int talepSayisi = rP.LastFiveDaysRequestCount();

    if (talepSayisi > 0)
    {
        return talepSayisi.ToString();

    }

    return "";
}
```

I would add a `CssClass` value to your `Label` control as that will make it easier to use in a jQuery selector, like this:

Markup:

```
<div id="panoramCouponBarLittleTalep">
    <asp:Label ID="LabelTalepSayisiSag" ClientIDMode="Static" 
               Text="" runat="server" CssClass="TheLabel" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000); // 5000 MS == 5 seconds
});

function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PageName.aspx/GetRequestCount",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            // Put result of call into label
            $('.TheLabel').text(result);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Note: Obviously you can adjust the timer interval value to be larger or smaller, depending upon your needs and performance. Also, the `CssClass` value on the `Label` control avoids the name mangling issue that plagues ASP.NET server controls. Even though you are using the `ClientIDMode="Static"`, I like to avoid using the ID of a server control in jQuery when possible, because a class name will not get mangled by ASP.NET.

Comment: I was trying your suggestion, then I realized that in function ajaxCall(), at this part: url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName" :

I'm using master page, so i cant't pass PageName.aspx. Is there a way to give master page name? it's name is Admin.Master

Comment: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods do not work inside of a master page, or at least I have never gotten them to work. You can put your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method in another page though, it will work across page files, because they are static and do not require the instance of the page class. The exception to "anywhere" being the master page.

Comment: you are right, shame on me because of asking this question :) it helped a lot..thank you...

Comment: @Samet - no problem, glad it helped you out. Feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP Page Methods to do it:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm

Comment: Yes, this was on my mind too. on the link you showed me, there is a part like this:

    <script>
        function test(){
            alert(PageMethods.MyMethod("Paul Hayman"));
        }
    </script>

Question comes up here: How to call this function test() in every x seconds...

Comment: @user3018157 - `setInterval()` is a JavaScript function for calling something every x milliseconds. See my answer for an example of doing just that.